# Hide a OPENSSL RSA PublicKey from cracker

Tags: openssl, rsa, cracking

Background:
I want to protect my software from cracker and I have use VMProtect, but since that VMP can't protect the memory search and  modifications. my RSA Public key is under a risk of being changed or spotted.

in this case. since my software is based on web licensing. if the public key is spotted.  cracker will be able to decrypt data from server and find out what is my license format. and if the cracker modify the public key, and host a new server with their own private key and then change the DNS to that server, software will be cracked.

Question:

in this case. the public key should never be published, and in OPENSSL I have a big problem with RSA Key format. it is always like this :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBALrBdN8F83hT2+pBsAwiNx+v3FWp51IdEElE8UvVhfZYmePbitpzLcJi
jZ4/tvRFXJGhqa3PKPUQkH2F4VrHruA2kNceiL/Btywc9oM+tDMeX1jcRKwXwK1k
KdccKwn0qywG6YxQuqWQIotOfV+IIuhcHdaHBl6CZ05/cBo6AlMlAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

or this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQC7vbqajDw4o6gJy8UtmIbkcpnkO3Kwc4qsEnSZp/TR+fQi62F79RHWmwKOtFmwteURgLbj7D/WGuNLGOfa/2vse3G2eHnHl5CB8ruRX9fBl/KgwCVr2JaEuUm66bBQeP5XeBotdR4cvX38uPYivCDdPjJ1QWPdspTBKcxeFbccDw==
```

in any of this case, the key has a clear format and the cracker can just search for the string and they will find my public key way too easy.

is there anyway to generate a RSA Public key that has no format such as:

1.no string before or after RSA key that makes a format.(no stuff like BEGIN blah blah blah END blah blah blah)

2.not a key based on string: if it's possible , base on byte will be perfect(key is not a string but hex,like :0x12,0xDA,0x77,...)

3.if it's possible,avoid using a specific length with the key: it will be perfect if  sometimes generate and get a key that is  98 Bytes long sometimes generate and get a key that is  137 bytes long etc.

so if I can have a public key like this kind, even it's in memory,cracker will never able to find where the key is. but I can't find OPENSSL has any doc about this.

is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide a *public* key? You would ordinarily sign your license data using your private key, and then use the public key to verify the signature, if it verifies then the license data is valid, if not the license has been tampered with and should be rejected. In such a scheme there's no particular issue in having someone view your license data or private key, because even if they create a valid license file they can't create a valid signature for it without the private key.

Answer (score 3):

This question has no exact solution. You can hide a public key, private key, or whatever as hard as you want and "there will always be a way to reverse engineer" this. You can always be cracked anyway.

The problem then turns to: **HOW MUCH** efford you wanna spend on hide your information to make that reverse engineer as much difficult as possible for a cracker?

And then, you have many solutions. I suggest you to look for **obfuscators** and/or **white box cryptography** [if you are ready to spend some money for your application]. Those are common techniques used to hide information and make the life of crackers much harder.

Comment: right now I think I just want the public key has no specific format and I think that will makes much more difficult to crack.  because right now if I using something like cheat engine I can just search string "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY" and I will find the key in memory and replace it way too easy. this is too weak.

Comment: sorry, is this key in a text file or it is bound to the executable?

Comment: it's a constant and will be load in memory  so it's bound to the executable like this:  char rsapubkey[] = {"key...........endkey"}

Comment: so, obfuscate it... what is the problem?

Comment: if we obfuscate it, when  calling BIO_new_mem_buf we still have to decrypt public key from obfuscate  and put it into openssl, it is still a risk.  I think it's better if a public key has no format so people will never beable to find out this is a public key by just look binary of the memory.

Comment: there's a way to use the public key in other formats, but you are still using OpenSSL. For a cracker it doesn't matter if it's a string or a buffer with bunch of stuff. One can inspect that functions anyways and grab your key easily. For this level of security, you can't use OpenSSL. You must use white box cryptography.

Comment: is there any kind of  white box cryptography protect software I can use? or I must do it myself?

Comment: I don't think so... it is usually proprietaty code. You need a third part company to apply it to your code... it's very expensive. It's not the kind of thing you find open-source and implement by yourself easily, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest thing you can do is to convert your key from PEM to DER format, which is also supported by OpenSSL tools. Mostly you need to add another argument to make it accept.

DER is a binary format, so without any clues it can look as binary gibberish. But of course it has its internal structure (ASN.1).

PEM is a Base64-encoded DER with added delimeters such as those `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` lines.